# Is "disproportionate" word correct in this context or should I use other?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, definition

Imagine the next situation, I am talking with a friend about this article: [Haiti: photojournalist shot in face as senator opens fire outside parliament](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2019/sep/23/haiti-shooting-senator-gun-parliament-photojournalist) ...:

> Friend: Ehh, Did you read this one?
>
> Me: Ahh yes, I read it this morning.
>
> Me: I think his reaction was **disproportionate**, he could has handled the situation in a better way ...

**Disproportionate** means:

> too large or too small in comparison to something else, or not deserving its importance or influence
>
> - There are a disproportionate number of girls in the class.
> - The country's great influence in the world is disproportionate to its relatively small size.

Source: [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/disproportionate)

I am using disproportionate to refer an **action** of him, I am not talking about: shapes, numbers (for example: ehh look that team is disproportionate, it has the double of players than the others), ...

So, as I asked: **Is "disproportionate" word correct in this context?**

Comment: I don't understand the point of your question and the text you cite.

Comment: @Lambie It's not useful to leave such vague comments. The question is fine and understandable, and is asking about the usage of a word (*disproportionate*) in a sentence (*I think his reaction was disproportionate*).

Comment: All answers were really helpful, they opened my mind a little more in a way that I saw english language as rigid, but... your comments helped me to see it less rigid now. I will explain this, I tried to communicate an idea perfectly (choosing the perfect words) but I see now that I can communicate an idea in many ways (I have many word choices).

Answer (score 2):

It's fine, although I think you need to better define *what* reaction was disproportionate, and *how* it was disproportionate.  For example:

> Drawing a handgun and firing randomly into the crowd seems like a disproportionate response to the level of threat.  It doesn't seem like he was in any real danger.

Also I think you mean to say "handled", not "lead".

> I think the senator could have **handled** the situation in a better way.

Comment: I fixed it. Yes, "**handled**" sounds much better.

Answer (score 2):

I think that’s a good choice, especially noting that the senator remarked

> “Armed individuals threatened me. It was proportional. Equal force, equal response.”

You could say it’s a bit of wordplay.

However, as the entry shows, you can/should use *to* to indicate what it’s relative to. For example,

> I think his reaction was disproportionate *to the alleged threat.*

I would say that “disproportionate” is a tad on the formal side. If you want an common, slightly less formal word, consider  *overreact*:

> - [overreact](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overreact)
>     : to react to something too strongly : to respond to something with too strong an emotion or with unnecessary or excessive action
>     // I was furious and yelled at him. He told me I was overreacting and to "chillax."
>     — Ben Stein
>     (M-W)
> - [overreact](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/overreact)
>     Respond more emotionally or forcibly than is justified.
>     ‘the Authority are urging people not to overreact to the problem’
>     (Lexico)

Example:

> I think he overreacted. He could have handled it better.

Comment: There's no general indication to add *to* after the word, unless the context requires it. *His response was disproportionate.* is perfectly sufficient, unless one wants to say more.

Answer (score -2):

I don't feel like **disproportionate** is the best choice here. How about **uncalled-for**:

> his reaction was **uncalled-for**, he could has lead the situation in
>   a better way

Also, I'm thinking of **excessive**, but I'm not sure if it fits the context.

Comment: Both the words you suggest mean different things. You have to explain why *disproportionate* doesn't work. (–1)